# Has anyone encountered any issues using jQuery.getJSON() with PetFinder API URL request string?

Tags: jquery, api

URL query string gives me the correct response in the appropriate format but I cannot implement in on the webpage.

I tried doing the script below, with the correct GET parameters, to test but it does not return anything, even the alert.

I figured the issue is with the URL because I tried https://graph.facebook.com/zombies
as the url and it worked.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $.getJSON('http://api.petfinder.com/pet.find?key=1234567890&location=&format=json', function(pet)  
    {      
           alert("hi!");
    });

</script>
```

Is there any way get around this issue? 
Thanks!

Comment: @christiandev, thanks. first timer, sorry.

Comment: If you visit https://www.petfinder.com/developers/api-docs, you can get your own key by registering. The key is provided as soon as your account is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the URL directly, you recieve an XML response, telling you that the key you used `1234567890` is invalid. I presume this is a demo key you took from their documentation, but often with APIs you need to regiser your own application, and use your applications API key in the requests.

Result XML

```
<petfinder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd">
 <header>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <timestamp>2013-09-25T19:32:59Z</timestamp>
  <status>
   <code>300</code>
   <message>unauthorized key</message>
  </status>
 </header>
</petfinder>
```

Comment: you're correct, it is just a demo key. i get the correct response with the url query string i have with me. it is just that jQuery.getJSON() does not give me anything once i pass the url to the function. i also changed the encoding per your advice and used &amp; and %2c for & and the comma. still nothing.. thanks so much for checking.